# How to see habit items along the timegrid like normal items?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to know how to see habit items like normal items. Along the time-grid in their place and not at the bottom of the day. Maybe it's on the sorting algorithm ? Or there is a variable that I can customize?

Thanks!

Comment: What does 'in their place' mean?  In the agenda?  What does the scheduled time look like?

Comment: Ok, I was doing the example and noticed that the the problem is not because they're scheduled. It's because they're habits (org-habit module).  [Example](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/daily_plan.png) My habits with time are at the end, like those scheduled items without time.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. For having habits placed along the timegrid and not in the end you have to modify the sorting strategy taking the habit-down part.

```
(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy
  '((agenda time-up priority-down category-keep)
    (todo   priority-down category-keep)
    (tags   priority-down category-keep)
    (search category-keep)))
```

This way it works.